# Why does MS-SQL-Server (all versions) cast 1.0/12.0 as numeric(8,6)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to explain a 101.10 difference in value.

303'300'000/12 is about 25'275'000.
However, according to MS-SQL, it's 25'274'898.90.

Consider this (dumbed down) SQL-statement:

```
SELECT 
     303300000.00/12.0 AS a 
    ,1.0/12.0*303300000.00 AS b
    ,1.0/12.0 AS omg 
    ,1.0/CAST(12.0 AS float) AS expected 
    ,0.083333*303300000.0 AS r1 
    ,0.083333333333333300 * 303300000.0 AS r2
```

[image: astounding results]

I thought since I wrote 1.0/12.0 it would cast as **float** 
(which is itselfs dumb, but that's another story), 
but apparently, it's `decimal (8,6)`

```
CREATE VIEW dbo._Test
AS
SELECT 1.0/12.0 as xxx



SELECT 
     COLUMN_NAME
    ,DATA_TYPE
    ,NUMERIC_PRECISION
    ,NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '_Test' 


DROP VIEW dbo._Test
```

Is there any reason to this madness ? 
How does it determine the precision ? 
Is there any notation to force float, without the need for a cast statement ?

If I run the same query on PostgreSQL, pg does it right...

[image: postgre does it right]

Comment: This is [documented under "Precision, Scale and Length"](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The rules are not easy to digest, and they attempt to preserve as many digits before the decimal point before they go to preserving as many after the decimal point. `FLOAT` constants can be constructed by using `E` notation, which can be as simple as `1e`. Of course, binary floating-point comes with its own precision issues...

Comment: Incidentally, a more convenient way of determining the type of your expression than creating a table and querying the metadata is using `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1.0/12.0, 'BaseType'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1.0/12.0, 'Precision'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1.0/12.0, 'Scale')`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: I know what the machine epsilon is, so no surprises there. Interesting, so correct is 1.0e/12.0e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation: [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Specifically it states:

> The operand expressions are denoted as expression e1, with precision
>   p1 and scale s1, and expression e2, with precision p2 and scale s2.
>   The precision and scale for any expression that is not decimal is the
>   precision and scale defined for the data type of the expression.
>
> ```
> Operation     Result precision                        Result scale *
> e1 + e2       max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1     max(s1, s2)
> e1 - e2       max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1     max(s1, s2)
> e1 * e2       p1 + p2 + 1                             s1 + s2
> e1 / e2       p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)      max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
> ```

The important part here is the last one. In your case, you have a `decimal(2,1)` and a `decimal(3,1)`. For precision, this results in:

```
 2 - 1 + 1 + max(6,1 + 3 + 1) = 2 + max(6,5) = 2 + 6 = 8
```

For the scale, we get:

```
max(6,1+3+1) = max(6,5) = 6
```

Take the resulting values and as a result you get a `decimal(8,6)`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the precision and scale for multiplication and division of `decimal`/`numeric` is a mystical art.  SQL Server does explain the rationale in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> In multiplication and division operations we need precision - scale
>   places to store the integral part of the result. The scale might be
>   reduced using the following rules:
>
> 1. The resulting scale is reduced to min(scale, 38 – (precision-scale)) if the integral part is less than 32, because it
>      cannot be greater than 38 – (precision-scale). Result might be rounded
>      in this case.
> 2. The scale will not be changed if it is less than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, overflow error might
>      be raised if it cannot fit into decimal(38, scale)
> 3. The scale will be set to 6 if it is greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and
>      scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6). Result
>      might be rounded to 6 decimal places or overflow error will be thrown
>      if integral part cannot fit into 32 digits.

Because I have never had a need to implement this functionality, I must honestly say that I'm not sure I have ever really understood the logic (I'm sure it makes a lot of sense).  My take-away from the explanation is:  If I care about the precision and scale of the result, then I'll cast after the arithmetic operation.

Somewhere in that explanation I see "6", so that explains the scale part.  I'm sure the precision follows from equally direct logic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fact that [literals like 1.0 and 12.6 are of decimal (numeric) type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#decimal-constants). 1.0 is precision 2 and scale 1, 12.0 is precision 3 and scale 2.

The result of the expression 1.0/12.0 is of type decimal (numeric) [because the highest precendence of the types is decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#result-types) (both types are decimal).

As for the [precision and scale of the expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the formulas are:

```
expr        precision                           scale
e1 / e2     p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)  max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

So,

> precision=2-1+1+max(6,1+3+1)=2-1+1+6=8

and

> scale=max(6,1+3+1)=6